# React child re-renders every time parent renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As I have shown in below, react child renders every time it's parent renders.
Why is that and is that an issue?
Also how can I avoid it such that child re renders only when it's pros change.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Main></Main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

function Main() {
    const [count, updateFlag] = useState(0);

    function onButtonClick(newCount) {
        updateFlag(newCount);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>onButtonClick(count + 1)}>Main Button {count}</button>
            <Sub>ds</Sub>
        </div>
    );
}

function Sub() {
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log('useEffect called');
    });
    return(
        <div>This is sub</div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The virtual DOM implemented in React works in this way. When a parent updates all child elements are also updated

You can prevent child elements from re-render if the props do not change for them using [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for functional components and by extending `PureComponent` for class components. You could also implement a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` method in class component for more finegrained controlling

Changing to the below code for Sub component will not re-render it if the parent updated. This is because no props are passed to it and hence nothing changes for this component. If props are passed React.memo performs a shallow comparison before deciding to trigger render. You can also pass in the second parameter to `React.memo` for finegrained controlling

```
const Sub = React.memo(() {
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log('useEffect called');
    });
    return(
        <div>This is sub</div>
    );
})
```

Comment: So normally is it encouraged to use React.memo like techniques? because in a large component tree, all child components will be re rendered unnecessarily otherwise

Comment: The developer has to carefully choose when to use memo and when to not. Sometime if the component has to re-render frequently the use of memo can be a overhead. However the react render is fast enough to avoid use of memo if there is a 50-50 change that the component actually has to re-render

Comment: you say that react rendering is very fast and efficient right?

Comment: yes, reacts rendering is fast and efficient and memo or purecomponent are ways to improve it even further but needs to be used cautiously